# Can't connect to mysql via tcp/ip.But able to connect via socket

Tags: mysql, linux

System: CentOS 7.3.1611

MySQL: 5.6.47

It is similar to --skip-networking option. But there is no skip-networking in my.cnf

1. Using `ps aux|grep mysql` can find mysql service.

```
 ~]# ps aux|grep mysql
root      2233  0.8  0.0 115444  1688 ?        S    16:59   0:00 /bin/sh /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/www/server/data --pid-file=/www/server/data/izbp1etbb1qeqmfrz9agzuz.pid --sql-mode=NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
mysql     2872  6.4 15.8 1074428 297900 ?      Sl   16:59   0:00 /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/www/server/mysql --datadir=/www/server/data --plugin-dir=/www/server/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --sql-mode=NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/www/server/data/izbp1etbb1qeqmfrz9agzuz.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3366
root      2896  0.0  0.0 112712   952 pts/0    R+   16:59   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

2. Both of`netstat -talnp | grep 3306`and`lsof -i :3306` return nothing.
3. When using `mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -p` would return `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`,but `mysql -uroot -hlocalhost -p` can access.

my.cnf

```
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

[mysqld]
port        = 3366
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
datadir = /www/server/data
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
performance_schema_max_table_instances = 400
table_definition_cache = 400
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 32M
max_allowed_packet = 100G
table_open_cache = 128
sort_buffer_size = 768K
net_buffer_length = 4K
read_buffer_size = 768K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
thread_cache_size = 16
query_cache_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 32M
sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
local-infile=0
skip_symbolic_links=yes

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = true
#skip-name-resolve
max_connections = 500
max_connect_errors = 100
open_files_limit = 65535

log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed
server-id = 1
expire_logs_days = 10
slow_query_log=1
slow-query-log-file=/www/server/data/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=3
#log_queries_not_using_indexes=on


innodb_data_home_dir = /www/server/data
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /www/server/data
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_read_io_threads = 1
innodb_write_io_threads = 1

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 500M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 768K
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
```

error page

```
Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

error-log

```
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-02-25 17:30:26 7117 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.47 started; log sequence number 7634069
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /www/server/data//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /www/server/data//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3366
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2020-02-25 17:30:27 7117 [Note] /www/server/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have limited innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads to 1?  
Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have `port` set to 3366, but you're trying to connect via the default port of 3306. Use `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3366 ...` to specify the port you're using.

You're still using the default unix domain socket path `/tmp/mysql.sock`, so connecting via that method works without extra options.